# error: linker command failed: ld: duplicate symbol _main

Tags: xcode

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It says that i have:

> ld: duplicate symbol _main in       /Users/timpark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tutorial-    gsmmwsvdohwbiqforobplztheaso/Build/Intermediates/tutorial.build/Debug/tutorial.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/tutorial.o and /Users/timpark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tutorial-gsmmwsvdohwbiqforobplztheaso/Build/Intermediates/tutorial.build/Debug/tutorial.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o for architecture x86_64"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linker command failed: duplicate symbol \_main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816384/linker-command-failed-duplicate-symbol-main)

Answer (score 3):

`duplicate symbol _main` means you have multiple main.m under Targets/Compiled Sources. Check out and remove it.